# How to check whether 2 dbids intersect in 2D drawing?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a 2D drawing and I need extract properties from all dbIds if they intersect with current dbId.

It will be enough something like that:

```
function checkIntersect(dbId1, dbId2){
  return intersect ? true : false
}
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try find the 2d bounds (bounding boxes) of the two nodes using:

```
function get2DBoundsSample( dbId, model, useInstancing ) {

    //const it = model.getData().instanceTree;

    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();



    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

    let bc = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback( bounds );

    const dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;

    const fragIds = dbId2fragId[dbId];



    if( Array.isArray( fragIds ) ) {

        for( let i = 0; i < fragIds.length; i++ ) {

            find2DBoundsSample( fragList, fragIds[i], dbId, useInstancing, bc );

        }

    } else if( typeof fragIds === 'number' ) {

        find2DBoundsSample( fragList, fragIds, dbId, useInstancing, bc );

    }

    function find2DBoundsSample( fragList, fragId, dbId, useInstancing, bc ) {

    const mesh = fragList.getVizmesh( fragId );

    if(mesh.geometry){

        const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader( mesh.geometry, useInstancing );

        vbr.enumGeomsForObject( dbId, bc );

    }

    else{

        console.log('Mesh Geometry undefined. DBID: ',dbId, fragId, useInstancing);

      }

    }

    return bc.bounds;

}
```

Then test if the two boxes intersects with `Box3.isIntersectionBox()`